# How to limit log rotations number in uWSGI?

Tags: logging, configuration, uwsgi

Is there any option to limit log rotations number using uWSGI config/ini? I would like to avoid external `/etc/logrotate.d/` setup.

My goal is to keep 2MB log files but not to spend more than 200MB space for logging.

Comment: Take a look at `logger` keyword `--logger file:logfile=/tmp/uwsgi.log,maxsize=200000000`
https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Logging.html#logging-to-files
I personally tried to pass `--logger` keyword as param to uwsgi and it works for me. I suppose it should be the same for config-style way.

Comment: Thanks @discort , it does rotate log files but it does not limit rotations number which is my concern.